# FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP on Galaxy S3 results in showing the android homescreen temporarily.

Tags: android, android-intent

This occurs both when the back button is overwritten or if I just make it an onclick on some other button.

What happens is that when the key is pressed, all activities are cleared, and the android's homescreen is shown for a second or so before the other.class is shown.

This does not occur on any other device I have tested.

Any input?

```
@Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                Intent switchScreen = new Intent(this, other.class);
                switchScreen.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(switchScreen);        }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct behavior.. However, the problem can be solved.

**Solution**

onCreate() of the other-`Activity`

```
Intent lIntent = new Intent(this, other.class);
lIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(lIntent);
```

and in your `Manifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".other"
          android:launchMode="singleTop">
...
</activity>
```

Comment: Sorry what should I add to the onCreate of the other activity?
I added the launchmode but the problem persists.

Comment: Aha! I removed the flag and added the launchmode and it fixed. Thanks!